Authentication manager and psycopg2
I need write a script in QGIS that have to read data from a recordset containing non geometric data, generated by an SQL expression on a PostgreSQL database. I have read that this can be done by using psycopg2.
In order to access the DB I want to use one of the pairs user/password stored in the authentication manager: the id of such profile is stored in a variable.
Can anyone give me and example of how to set the connection?

You might want to create a non geographic layer to load your data to Qgis first (use Qgis DB manager to define Server address, user/pwd). And then Access that data from your script
